# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I don't understand what is causing the problem the query works fine in the MongoDB shell

```
public IEnumerable<BsonDocument> GetExams()
        {
            // db.exams.aggregate([
            // {$unwind:"$exams"},
            // {$project : {provider:1,exams:{ name:1,count: {$size :"$exams.questions" }} } },
            // {$group: {_id:"$provider",exams:{$push:"$exams"}} },
            // {$project: {_id:0,provider:"$_id",exams:"$exams"} }
            // ])

            return _examsCollection.Aggregate()
                .Unwind("exams")
                .Project(new BsonDocument
                {
                    {"provider", 1},
                    {
                        "exams",
                        new BsonDocument {{"name", 1}, {"count", new BsonDocument {{"$size", "$exams.questions"}}}}
                    }
                })
                .Group(new BsonDocument {{"_id", "$provider"}, {"exams", new BsonDocument {{"$push", "$exams"}}}})
                .Project(new BsonDocument {{"_id", 0}, {"provider", "$_id"}, {"exams", "$exams"}})
                .ToList();
}
```

this is the error code

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.    at
> get_AsBoolean(Object )    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWrite(WriteStackFrame&
> current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.Write(WriteStack& state,
> Utf8JsonWriter writer)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32
> originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions
> options, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object
> value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: can you provide the db data which causes this error? Pay attention that the error can be related to the structure of the particular document

Comment: so I would suggest to post a minimum repro app which will contain two steps: 1. Inserting data into an empty collection. 2. Running the above script which leads to the error